# How to show basis of the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable.

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces

How can I prove that the basis of the vector space $\mathbb{R}$  over $\mathbb{Q}$ is uncountable.

By vector space $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ we mean $\mathbb R$ with addition and scalar multiplication as described, for example, in this post: [Prove $\mathbb R$ vector space over $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498186/prove-mathbb-r-vector-space-over-mathbb-q)

A set $B$ is a basis of $\mathbb R$ over $\mathbb Q$ if every real number $x$ can be expressed uniquely as 
$$x = q_1b_1+\dots+q_nb_n,$$
where $q_1,\dots,q_n\in\mathbb Q$ and $b_1,\dots,b_n\in B$.

Comment: If the basis were counatable, so would be the space. We yould have $\mathbb R\cong \mathbb Q[X]$.

Comment: What would be that basis, I can't seem to find one?

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583601/take-mathbbr-as-a-vector-space-over-mathbbq-then-a-basis-for-mathbb

Comment: Since the question seems to have been abandoned by the OP and it [received some close votes](http://math.stackexchange.com/review/close/354609), I tried to improve the question. (I think that it is useful to have post about this topic on the site.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that $B$ is a countable base for $\Bbb R$ over $\Bbb Q$. Then every real number can be written in the form

$$q_1b_1+q_2b_2+\ldots+q_nb_n$$

for some positive integer $n$ and $n$-tuples $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}\in B^n$ and $\langle q_1,q_2,\dots,q_n\rangle\in\Bbb Q^n$.

1. How many positive integers are there?
2. How many elements does $\Bbb Q^n$ have?
3. How many elements does $B^n$ have?
4. How many combinations of $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, $\{b_1,b_2,\dots,b_n\}\in B^n$ and $\langle q_1,q_2,\dots,q_n\rangle\in\Bbb Q^n$ are there altogether?

Comment: Aren't you assuming that B is finite? B can be countably infinite too.