# Infinite dimensional space with metric generated by norm

Tags: functional-analysis

In my classwork I have to provide examples of infinite dimensional vector spaces with metric generated by their norm. I readily provide space of continuous function $C[a, b]$ and Hilbert sequence space $\mathscr l^2$ with their respective norm as the easiest examples, but I am still looking for a few more **simple** examples.

From this old MSE link [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466707/what-are-some-examples-of-infinite-dimensional-vector-spaces) I see that the function space $L^p$ and the polynomials in one variable $\mathbb R[x]$ are also simple examples. I know from other resources that the norm to the function space $L^p$ is

$$\lVert f \rVert_p = \left( \int^a_b \lvert f(x) \rvert^p dx \right)^{\frac{1}{p}}$$
which I think is capable of generating a metric by $ d(f, g) = \lVert f - g \rVert_p$.

And here is my question: Does anyone know of a norm to the above polynomials in one variable $\mathbb R [x]$ that is capable of generating a metric? Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: Every norm generates a metric, so any norm on polynomials will do (and there are lots to choose from.)

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing that out! Can you give me an example of the norm, even the simplest one? Thanks again.

Comment: You can identify $\mathbb R [x]$ with a subspace of all the real sequences (in which all the terms are zero excepting finitely many); in this subspace the simplest nom is $||p||= Max |a_n|$ where $a_n$ are the coefficients of the polynomial $p$.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much!